# Show related div when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I created a `ul` containing `li` elements. I want to to slide down a `div` when a link in the same `li` is clicked.

The problem is when I click the link all `div`s are shown.

I use PHP for setting the id on each link.

The html code is here:

```
  <li class='post'>
    <div class='link'>
      <a href='#'id=". * Here is Post ID * ."></a>
    </div>
    <div class='slidedown'>//here is what I want to sliding</div>
  </li>
```

The jQuery code is here :

```
$(".link a").click(function(){

    var id_post = $(this).attr("id");

    $(".slidedown").slideDown("slow");

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parent()` to move up one parent. Since the container were looking for is the `.post` we'll have to move up 2 parents. Then we can find the child of it that is `.slidedown` and slide that one down with `.slideDown()`

```
$(".link a").click(function(){

    $(this).parent().parent().children('.slidedown').slideDown("slow");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even more easy:

**jQuery**

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.slidedown').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Or you use:

```
$('.link a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.slidedown').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Go to [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) at jQuery Docs to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works well:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
     $(this).siblings('.slidedown').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to move up a level and [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to target the next sibling:

```
$(".link a").click(function(){
  $(this).parent(".link").next(".slidedown").slideDown("slow");
  return false;
});
```

Or you can access the `.post` using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and target the `.slidedown` using [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$(".link a").click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".post").find(".slidedown").slideDown("slow");
  return false;
});
```